# How does GridFS work within Meteor?

Tags: file, ionic-framework, meteor, file-upload, gridfs

I'm working on an application where an admin can upload a schedule (just a file), and an user can download that uploaded file. It is working now with an upload function within Meteor and the decoded file is saved to the Mongo DB.

The problem is that I can only upload files that are around 16mb. I did some research and apparently you can fix this with GridFS. I'm very new to this and the documentation doesn't seem to help at all. Can someone give me a simple example of how to use GridFS to solve my issue? Or does anyone recommend any other solutions?

This is my UploadSchedule method that I use for uploading the file to the server:

```
uploadSchedule() {
    if (this.fileListNextMonth == null) {
      this.alertController.create(
        {
          title: "Error",
          subTitle: "Cannot upload file!",
          buttons: ['Ok']
        }
      ).present();
    } else {
      this.fileName = this.fileList[0].name;

      this.getBase64(this.fileList[0]).then(
        data =>
          this.scheduleProvider.uploadSchedule(data, this.fileName, true).then(observable => {
            const subscription = observable.subscribe(data => {
              console.log("data: " + data);
            }, err => console.error(err), () => subscription.unsubscribe());
          })
      );
    }
  }
```

In my ScheduleProvider there is a method (uploadSchedule) that does a post request to the server with the specific file. In the backend I simply do an Insert with the file that has been uploaded, so it wil be saved to the database as a string.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a package like https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files because it is well documented, tested and also allows you to use other locations such as AWS S3 for file storage.

You can use gridfs directly. but I wouldn't recommend it.

If you really want to just store your files in your Mongo database, there is a good package here: https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection which will help make the job a little easier.

I have used both of these packages myself, and they work well.

There is also https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS which is a good package but is no longer actively maintained. I believe it is complex to use.

In your code it looks like you are converting your file to base64 representation, which works, but it does make the file quite a bit larger than the original file. On large files this can cause some performance challenges (as well as the additional memory it needs).

I would recommend storing your images or files on an external service such as S3, because it offloads the retrieval of them from the Meteor server, and you will notice a performance difference - it's like using a CDN for your assets.

Comment: I absolutely agree here... Especially if you have hosted mongo which you pay by the GB for service. Uploading files into the DB can quickly grow your hosting bill to a point where you regret it.